# How do I move elements from one list to another in Common Lisp - CLisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm trying to implement a Towers of Hanoi recursively with Common Lisp. I know what the recursive calls are and how they work, but I'm just lost with how I would go about moving something from the end of one list, to the end of another list. I was trying to do some research on how to do this, but I couldn't find anything online.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Adding/removing elements to/from the end of a list is not a good idea in Lisp. That's a slow operation.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the last element of a list with [butlast](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_butlas.htm#butlast), get last element with [last](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_last.htm), and you cat append a list to another list with [append](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_append.htm#append) (you just cons your element to be added so that it's a one element list). Working on the end of lists in CL are not optimal as every function needs to traverse the list in order to find the last one, but it is done when you need to add/remove in both ends.

With Tower of Hanoi you are stacking disks on top of each other and the last one put is the first one out. In Common Lisp (in fact any Lisp cousin) you can easily add to front and remove from front with doing `(cdr pole-a)` in the recursive call to remove the top element from `pole-a` and add to `pole-b` with `(cons (car pole-a) pole-b)` in the recursive call.

I imagine you need this to actually be able to see which disk is moved in each stage, since you need no such structure to calculate the moves needed. In such a scenario you only need the names of the poles and the level the recursion and the number of disks you want to move in this round.

Comment: I agree that that this should probably be implemented using lists as stacks.  If the solution isn't recursive, but iterative, you could also use `(push (pop pole-a) pole-b)` to “move” the element from the top of `pole-a` to `pole-b`, leaving both `pole-a` and `pole-b` with the expected values.